# эмуляция архитектуры powerpc64

Tags: linux, debian, virtualbox, виртуальная-машина, виртуализация

нужно сэмулировать архитектуру powerpc64 установить туда ос дебиан
возможно ли это все сделать на платформе windows10?
буду рад любой помощи

Comment: Наберите  в гугле `PowerPC Architecture Emulator` и вы получите не только положительный ответ на свой вопрос, но и кучу практичных (не проверял, но хочется в это верить) ссылок на готовые решения (в т.ч. с исходниками под GPL)

Comment: `QEMU` должна смочь.